# Developing Visual Studio extensions that work in the Windows and Mac versions

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-mac

I'm using Windows and I have a need for adding custom *Visual Studio (VS)* snippets to my project, but some of the project contributors have a Mac and, as such, use *Visual Studio for Mac*. From what I've seen, the only possible way to create extensions for *VS for Mac* is by using a Mac.

What I'd like to know is, what can I use to create either a cross-version extension, that works in *VS* and *VS for Mac*, or, on a worst case scenario, how can I create extensions for *VS for Mac* on Windows?

Comment: You will need to build MonoDevelop from source code so as to create an extension for VS for Mac on Windows.

Comment: Extensions for VS for Windows are not compatible for VS for Mac. VS for Mac it's MonoDevelop in past with its own extensions. But I think it's possible to create project where all necessary jobs will be done. This project shouldn't have references on VS assemblies. And two integration projects with necessary references. One for Windows and another for Mac. Also I think here will be 2 solutions. So you will have the one common assembly and two specific assemblies.